# Скачать картинку используя blob js

Tags: javascript

Я загрузил картинку на свой сайт(сайт работает локально, только на моем пк) и добавил на страницу кнопку.

Подскажите как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку картинка скачивалась на мой пк (желательно сделать это используя blob в JavaScript)